# Adding objects from a constructor to an ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm trying to create an ArrayList with cars I've created using a constructor class and then afterwards use a foreach loops to then print the model name of each cars.

I've created the car objects as following

```
Car car1 = new Car("Audi e-tron", "Black", 2021);
Car car2 = new Car("Audi RS7", "Black", 2021);
Car car3 = new Car("Audi A5", "Black", 2021);
```

I created the ArrayList and attempted to begin adding the car objects to the ArrayList

```
ArrayList carList = new ArrayList();
carList.Add(car1);
carList.Add(car2);
carList.Add(car3);
```

I tested to see if the code was working properly up to this point and checked if the ArrayList  has populated

```
Console.WriteLine("car list: {0}", carList[0]);
```

but that returns

```
ArrayListPractice.MainClass+Car
```

How can I add objects from the constructor to the ArrayList and return a parameter of the object? Thank you!

Comment: We have 2021, why you stil use an `ArrayList`?? Use a `List<Car>`

Comment: You are doing it correctly, it is just that calling ToString() on an object that does not have ToString() overriden will just give you the class name. So, override ToString in `Car` to output what you want to see. Also, why are you using ArrayList? That  is long dead.

Comment: hi there.  I would actually use the strongly typed List<> instead of ArrayList. So declare the list like this: var carList = new List<Car>(); Also, if you want to print the name you either need to override the ToString() function in the Car class or write something like: Console.WriteLine( carList[0].Name );

Comment: You might want to look at my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365412/c-how-can-i-add-an-object-into-array/65365550#65365550.  It doesn't directly address your issues, but it uses cars (which is why it sounded familiar) and touches on some aspects of your problems

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to print in the code block below?

```
Console.WriteLine("car list: {0}", carList[0]);
```

If you want to print the string property you passed into the constructor of the first element (`"Audi e-tron"`), for example, try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("car list: {0}", carList[0].Name); // 'Name' should be the field name you're looking for
```

Comment: As @Crowcoder pointed out above, added a `ToString` override to the `Car` class will provide a way to see the information about each car that you include in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the Car object, ToString() method and there is no need to other considerations, it will be automatically done