# Visual Studio is not registering the RemoveAt method in my code

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm quite new to C# and the concept of classes, and I was trying to make a program which takes player stats and prints them out. From there, I could edit this by deleting player stats or adding new ones. For reference, the classes I made are for JRPG classes, each having unique stats.

Before this I had made a character class with basic things shared between all classes such as character name and starting health, and then made several other classes which inherited those attributes plus their own, such as a Knight class having 60 Magic and a Wizard class having 140. I then made 10 characters whose stats I made into strings, such as "Barbarian Sigilford HP-100 Power-70 SpAtkPower-20 Speed-50" saved as the Player1Stats variable. the rest is as you see below. The added section is still a placeholder.

```
string[] stats = {Player1Stats, Player2Stats, Player3Stats, Player4Stats, Player5Stats, Player6Stats, Player7Stats, Player8Stats, Player9Stats, Player10Stats};
//The array I'm trying to delete from

PrintStats(stats);
//This is a method I made which just goes through the array and prints out each element

Console.WriteLine("\nPress P to print again, A to add a character, or D to delete a character.");
var input = Console.ReadKey();
switch (input.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.P:
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        PrintStats(stats);
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.A:
        Console.WriteLine("Added!");
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.D:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the row number of the character you would like to delete.");
        int indexNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        stats.RemoveAt(indexNo - 1);
        //The problem.
        Console.WriteLine("Deleted!");
        break;
}
```

For whatever reason, the editor is not even registering RemoveAt as a method. It didn't show up in the predictive window thingy. I tried making a test array of numbers 1 to 10 and the RemoveAt method worked as expected there, leading me to believe there is some problem with my array. If it helps, [this is the message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCZ5E.png).

Comment: You probably want a `List<string>` instead, which does have the `RemoveAt` method.

Comment: You may want to read my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365412/c-how-can-i-add-an-object-into-array/65365550#65365550 for a discussion of object based collections versus strongly typed collections as well as arrays versus other collection types

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The RemoveAt is an ArrayList Method. Try converting your `string[] stats` to an `ArrayList stats`

Take a look at the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.removeat?view=net-7.0)

Comment: The generic `List<T>`, mentioned in a comment, is much better.  `ArrayList` exists only because it was added when there were no generics.

Comment: There's been no reason to use `ArrayList` since 2005 (when `List<T>` made it into the framework. You want to use `List<string>` here